# Visual Studio Code C# - Go to Implementations/Definitions broken after reinstall

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-code

I have a bunch of C+ files that I have to convert to Python.
For that I installed VSC on Linux and opened the folder with the C# files. I was able to press F12 on a function call to jump to the definition - very helpful.
Yesterday I accepted the upgrade message for several files and ended up with an error of missing dotnet8 SDK. I have tried to install from the MS repository, but without success.
To make a long story short I finally uninstalled everything and installed VSC new (from the repository http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/).

Now the "Go to definition" Function always states "No definition found for ", even when it's in the same file.

I have absolutely no knowledge about VSC. I don't even know what information I can post here. I only have these few files. It's not a runable project, but the code search did work before.

What am I missing?
The python part is done with PyCharm, not with VSC.

I open the folder with the C# files in VSC.
Then open a file from the list.
Then place the cursor on a function call and press F12 (or right mouse button) to go to implementation or definition.

It should jump to that part in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code navigation (as well as code completion, refactoring, etc) are provided by the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol). Originally built for vscode, it's now been adopted by others (including neovim).

For C# in VSCode, this is provided by the [C# Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) (used to be called OmniSharp, so you might still see the old name in some documentation). The easiest way is to install it from the "Extensions" tab (side tab? I don't know what they call it). Do a search for it, and install either the `C#` extension by itself, or as part of the `C# Dev Kit` extension (which bundles it with a couple others).

If it's already installed, try removing it and reinstalling. If it still fails try nuking your `~/.vscode` dir, and potentially `~/.config/Code` as well (and lose all your config!)

Also, make sure you actually have `.NET 8 SDK` installed. Run `dotnet --list-sdks` on the terminal.

Comment: OmniSharp is not offered in VSCode for Linux and is not needed.   
dotnet-sdk is also not a solution. The whole trouble started with the upgrade to dotnet-sdk-8. Some parts are missing on Linux. (can't remember what - so many similar names...)   
But "dotnet --list-sdks" was a good hint. I had dotnet-host installed and no dotnet SDK at all. After installing dotnet-SDK-7 everything runs smoothly as before.